List of editable options with flow
I have a screen flow that needs to get a list of products and the possibility of editing values in the field, such as price and quantity.
I'm using a data table to get this list of products and display it, but there's no way to edit the values within the fields, has anyone done something similar or does anyone know of a component that can do this?

Currently in Salesforce Flow, you can't have edit functionality in flow-DataTable. However, if you want to use custom solution for this, you can follow this UnofficialSF guide : https://unofficialsf.com/datatable-lightning-web-component-for-flow-screens-2/

tanks for the answer, very good component maybe i can use, if possible
